# Folder Controllers created empty

Tags: php, symfony

I used Symfony version v4.4.1 . I create project in CLI using symfony command:

```sh
symfony new my_project_name --full
```

But my folder in `src/Controller` is empty, please, help. 
Maybe my Controllers are created in another directory. On screenshot, you can see trouble. 
Early, it's working nice. 
[image: application directory screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new application Controller directory is empty. It's a normal result when you use the *full* argument. Full will only specified that you have all common utilities/libraries (twig, security, etc). But you have to create your own business (entities, controllers, forms, views, etc).

If you want to create a Controller, you should install the maker bundle

```
symfony composer req maker --dev
```

Then the console will be able to create Controller as easy as:

```
symfony console make:controller MyNewController
```

Default controller is no longer in the empty application, because some applications do not need them. As example, if you are developing an API, you do not use controller. Another example, some developers do not use [MVC(model view controller) pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) but the [ADR (Action Domain Responder) Pattern](https://github.com/pmjones/adr)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, it works, but previously symfony created at least the default controller called page controller. why he stopped doing it, I don’t understand

Comment: Yes, it may be surpising. I edited my answer to explain why the DefaultController is no longer installed by default.